# Dragging E-Mails to the bottom of Foldertree does not scroll down

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I've got an E-Mail which I want to drag and drop into a folder within my mail-in ressource. The folder is on the very bottom of the folder tree, so it is usually not displayed; I have to scroll down to see the folder. So far so good. Usually, when dragging something in an scrollable area and you hit the e.g. bottom line of that area, it scrolls automatically down.

This is not the case with me and notes at the moment, and I was guessing there should be some setting to get desired effect. Unfortunately after hours of searching, I couldn't find a helpful answer .. Do you guys know if there is such a setting, that enables scrolling while dragging an E-Mail?

Edit: It's Lotus Notes Release 8.5.2FP4

Answer (score 0):

It should scroll, there isn't any setting that I know of that would disable the scrolling. Might be an issue with your mailfile design. You'll probably have to have your local Notes admin take a look.